# Remove and update Stacked Area chart with d3

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have a stacked Area Chart using D3 that renders and displays fine.  The chart also has a legend.

The issue is that I need to chart to update when a user clicks/taps on one of the legend entries.  And by update I mean remove the entry that was selected and redraw the chart with the remaining values.

I have the interaction working fine (selecting a Legend item triggers the redraw) but I can't get it to remove the no longer existing entry on the chart.  If I add `path.exit().remove()` to the code below it always removes the top most path no matter what entry was selected.

If I update using the second chunk of code it does redraw properly and even removes the correct entry from the chart save for the top most. It never removes that one.

I've tried combining the two as well to no avail. Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

```
svg.selectAll(".layer")
            .data(layers);

path.enter().append("path")
            .attr("class", "layer")
            .attr("d", function(d) { return area(d.values); })
            .style("fill", function(d, i) { return d.color });
```

Update chart:

```
svg.selectAll(".layer")
            .data(layers)
            .attr("d", function(d) { return area(d.values); })
            .style("fill", function(d, i) { return d.color || color(d.label); })
            .transition() // start a transition to bring the new value into view
            .ease("linear")
            .duration(500)
```

Comment: By default, D3 matches elements according to their array index. That is, if you pass in an array that is one element shorter, the last element will be in the `.exit()` selection. You can supply a function that tells D3 what to match on in the second argument to `.data()`.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff That get's me part way there.  Allow me to try and rephrase.  Using the fiddle below as an example I can easily remove the red or green paths, but if I do there is a gap there.  I need to be able to redraw the chart so that the gap is missing. As if it was never there to begin with.  Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/adeaver/FRNbq/9/

Comment: I was able to build off of @LarsKotthoff and get it working.  Thanks.